# When using JBoss's DatabaseServerLoginModule, what is the intended purpose of the RoleGroup column in the database?

Tags: authentication, jboss

I have been experimenting with the DatabaseServerLoginModule in JBoss and I have been **successful** in getting it to work. **However**, I'm puzzled by the following.

According to documentation about the DatabaseServerLoginModule (e.g. its JavaDoc), it is based on two logical tables:

- Principals(PrincipalID text, Password text)
- Roles(PrincipalID text, Role text, RoleGroup text)

The Principals table is straightforward, as are the two first columns of the Roles table, "PrincipalID" and "Role". However, **why is there a "RoleGroup" column**? From my experiments it seems to me that, in order to make the DatabaseServerLoginModule work properly in JBoss, you have to make it ***not*** use that column, as follows.

*Either*

1. configure DatabaseServerLoginModule with the module-option

   `<module-option name="rolesQuery">
       SELECT Role, RoleGroup FROM Roles WHERE PrincipalID=?
   </module-option>`

   *and* set RoleGroup equal to the value "Roles" on every row in the table.

*or*

2. configure DatabaseServerLoginModule with the module-option

   `<module-option name="rolesQuery">
       SELECT Role, 'Roles' FROM Roles WHERE PrincipalID=?
   </module-option>`

   i.e. to make the SQL statement override the RoleGroup value with the value "Roles".

Why not instead just have only the "PrincipalID" and "Role" columns in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RoleGroup not only to set roles, but also to configure a caller Principal. The documentation says:

> The EAP security framework uses two well-known role sets with the names **Roles** and **CallerPrincipal**.
>
> - The **Roles** group is the collection of Principals for the named roles as known in the application domain under which the Subject has been authenticated. This role set is used by methods like the `EJBContext.isCallerInRole(String)`, which EJBs can use to see if the current caller belongs to the named application domain role. The security interceptor logic that performs method permission checks also uses this role set.
> - The **CallerPrincipal** Group consists of the single Principal identity assigned to the user in the application domain. The `EJBContext.getCallerPrincipal()` method uses the CallerPrincipal to allow the application domain to map from the operation environment identity to a user identity suitable for the application. If a Subject does not have a CallerPrincipal Group, the application identity is the same as operational environment identity.

Comment: Thanks, kwart! Still, though, I find the database "design" a little odd, like it's too general. I mean, it doesn't restrict the RoleGroup values in any way, although the only two useful values are "Roles" and "CallerPrincipal". Or is there any use case for other values? If yes, how can an EJB or Java EE web component check whether an authenticated user has a role in a RoleGroup named something else than "Roles"? The HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole method, for example, only considers the "Roles" RoleGroup.